# AngularJS, IE11, and SVG <use> inside anchors

Tags: angularjs, svg, internet-explorer-11

I am using SVG `<use>` sprites as described in this [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/) article. Those icons often live in anchors, as demonstrated below:

```
<a ui-sref="home">
    <svg class="rp-icon">
        <use xlink:href="#rp-home"></use>
    </svg>
    <span>Home</span>
</a>
```

I've hit an odd bug with AngularJS that only occurs in IE11 (not IE10, and didn't test any earlier IE versions).

Clicking directly on the icon throws the Angular error `Unable to get property 'nodeName' of undefined or null reference`, thrown in this Angular function:

```
function nodeName_(element) {
    return lowercase(element.nodeName || element[0].nodeName);
}
```

Clicking on the anchor, but not directly on the icon, works as expected.

Is this an Angular bug, or something wrong with my use of SVG  icons?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. I'm having nearly the exactly same problem??

Comment: @MikeYoung wrap the svg element in a div or span. I styled that wrapping element with display:inline-block, position:relative, and line-height:0.